# Constrain heatmap to landmass only on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a heatmap on a Google Map that plots activity of certain animals.  So far I have created a heatmap that does exactly what I want it to. What I am trying to do now though is constrain the heatmap layer to just land as the animals aren't active in the water.  Essentially what I want to do is create a mask on the heatmap layer the shape of the coast.  Is this possible?  I have thought of maybe doing an image overlay on the map but that seems hacky.  I am using v3 of the Google Maps api. Any help of a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Heatmap Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) or [Fusion Table Heatmaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#fusion_table_heatmaps)

> ***Heatmap Layer***
>
> - A heatmap is a visualization used to depict the intensity of data at geographical points. When the Heatmap Layer is enabled, a colored overlay will appear on top of the map. By default, areas of higher intensity will be colored red, and areas of lower intensity will appear green.
>     [image]
>
> ***Fusion Table Heatmaps***
>
> - Fusion Tables also provide limited support for heatmaps, where the density of matched locations is depicted using a palette of colors. Current heatmaps use a red (dense) to green (sparse) gradient to indicate the relative prevalence of associated locations. You enable a heatmap by setting the layer’s FusionTablesLayerOptions heatmap parameter to enabled: true.
>     [image]

[image]

Here's a tutorial about [Interactive Heatmaps with Google Maps API v3](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/interactive-heatmaps-with-google-maps-api/), there is one thing to note here when plotting the heat maps:

***Radius determines how large hot spots get and when they merge.***

You must take to consider the radius specially you are creating a heatmap for land mass only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer @Mr.Rebot  I have a heatmap plotting the points but I have increased the radius to compensate for the fact that the data points are far apart and also to get a more organic pattern. The problem I am running into though is that because of this large radius, if the point is close to a shoreline the outter  radius of the point spills into the water. Can this be avoided and masked to the shoreline? You can see what I mean [here.](http://proofs.schemedesigns.ca/wsoo)